# Sort by last 7 days in post list

Tags: wp-list-table

My post list design is good. But the list sorted by popular and it not working. Please see my code below and shed some light on it. I want to sort my posts by their popularity by views of last 7 days. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$params = array(
    'orderby'             => 'popular',
    'post_type'           => 'post',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => 4,
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
);
$query_data = pixwell_query($params);
while ($query_data->have_posts()) :
    $query_data->the_post();
    pixwell_post_list_4();
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: `popular` isn't a valid argument for `orderby`. WordPress doesn't track post popularity. Are you recording views over the last 7 days yourself?

Comment: I am new... It is possible but i cannot do it. Expert can help me

Comment: What's the `pixwell_query()` exactly? It seems a plugin/theme-specific question rather than WP core, and if so, it'd be off-topic asking such one in this forum.

Comment: I have 7 blocks,  the design is pixwell post list 4....I want to know post filter code- last 7 days popular by view

Comment: To repeat what Jacob said: we can't just give you post filter code for this because WordPress doesn't track post views over time. You'll need to record this somehow, either individual views or aggregated views in a way you can query for 'last 7 days'. I expect there are existing plugins that will do this, else you'll have to implement it yourself. And then you can write a query for it, but it'll be specific to however you've implemented this.